# AngularJS OnsenUI reload parent page on nav.popPage() in child page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm calling a function on ng-init and in that page I'm pushing a new page to the pageStack of navigator on a button click. And in the child page I'm popping the current page. Now I want to reload the parent page when the child page is removed from page stack.

**Here is the code:**

**HTML**

```
<ons-navigator var="nav" page="page1.html">

</ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="pageOneController" ng-init="reload()">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Page 1</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-button ng-click="nav.pushPage('page2.html')">Push Page</ons-button>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Page 2</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-button ng-click="nav.popPage();">Pop Page</ons-button>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

**AngularJS**

```
module.controller('pageOneController', function(){
    $scope.reload = function(){
        console.log('Page one controller reloaded');
    }
});
```

**Update**

one solution is to reload the app by using

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [new `pageReplace()`](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#method-replacePage) that comes with the [new Onsen UI 1.3.0](http://onsen.io/blog/onsenui-1-3-released/). You can pass it to the callback of `popPage()` like this:

```
$scope.popAndReplace = function() {
  $scope.nav.popPage({onTransitionEnd : function() {
     $scope.nav.replacePage('page1.html', { animation : 'none' } );
  }})
};
```

Working here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/gbJGZw

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this, but the reload function is not recalled on replacePage
So I'm reloading the whole application by using window.location.reload(true);

Comment: Check the console in the Codepen I provided. Every time you press the 'popPage' button a new message appears... so the reload function is being called.

Comment: However your answer seems to be right. Will try this when I'm done with the design of my app.

Comment: @danjarvis
Could just call: 
$scope.nav.replacePage('page1.html', { animation : 'none' } );

Without pop, according to documentation, navigator.replacePage substitutes the current page. No hiccups

Comment: @AdeAlejo It does replace the current page, but then he would have two 'page1.html' in the navigator page-stack.

Answer (score 4):

While Fran's answer works great, there is a small flicker / hiccup in the UI when the page gets replaced. I took a slightly different approach by using `insertPage()` and changing the order of ops. The end result is smoother UI flow:

```
$scope.replacePreviousPage = function(url) {
      var pages = $scope.nav.getPages(),
          index = pages.length - 2;

      if (index < 0)
          return;

      $scope.nav.insertPage(index, url);
      pages.splice(index, 1);
};
```

You can create another function to encapsulate the replacing and popping, or just call them like:

```
$scope.replacePreviousPage('views/page1.html');
$scope.nav.popPage();
```

I am thinking of patching this into `popPage()` as an option (i.e. `option.reloadPage`) and submitting a pull request.

Comment: Hey! Something like this has been added to Onsen UI 1.3.3-dev: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/pull/663

Now it is enough with `popPage({'refresh': true});`

It will be released soon :)

Comment: Hi @FranDios. I've facing a similar issue. But using 'refresh': true on popPage, doesn't re-load the controller, so I can't do the re-initialization of that page. Is there any other way out? The replacePage() thing causes a glitch in the UI.

Comment: @RohitJain  `refresh: true` is only in master branch at the moment.
danjarvis' solution is supposed to avoid the flickering so it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

danjarvis,

Thank you for the idea! I was struggling with Onsen coming from Ionic, so your example really helped. I slightly modified it and here is an alternative if anyone was interested. It wasn't destroying ons-pages for me, which I needed it to for handling some odd duplicate directive issues. Also, I had to go back more than one page sometimes.

```
//function to go back and reload controller
$rootScope.index = 0;
$rootScope.replacePreviousPage = function (url) {
    var c = 0;
    angular.forEach(nav.getPages(), function (v, i) {
        if (i >= $rootScope.index) {
            nav.getPages()[i].destroy();
            c++;
        }
    });
    nav.insertPage($rootScope.index, url);
    nav.popPage();
};

//back
$rootScope.back = function (page) {
    if (page === "index") {
        location.reload();
    } else {
        if (page === "version") {
            $rootScope.index = $rootScope.index - 2;
        } else {
            $rootScope.index--;
        }
        $rootScope.replacePreviousPage('templates/' + page + '.html');
    }
};

//forward
$rootScope.forward = function (page) {
    nav.pushPage('templates/' + page + '.html');
    $rootScope.index++;
};
```