# onsen navigator popPage, reload previous controller

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

Suppose I've 2 controllers - `C1` and `C2`. I do a `navigator.pushPage` from `v1.html` to `v2.html`. And then I do a `navigator.popPage` on `v2.html`. But the `popPage` doesn't reload the controller `C1`. I'm trying to figure out a way to reload the controller, but have not been able to do that. I tried with `popPage({refresh:true})` also, but that didn't help either. Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/rohit_jain/pen/eNbyEm.

Is there any way I can achieve what I want?

Here's the real example:

On `v1.html`, I'm displaying the `Cart` details - `total_cart_items` or `total_price`. There I've a button to move to `v2.html`, where I display `Cart` contents. On `v2.html`, the person can reset the cart, and then go back to page `v1.html`. Now, I want the reset cart action to change `total_cart_items` and `total_price` on `v1.html`. But that's not happening.

Comment: Are you trying to reset certain models in the controller by reloading it ?? Why not call a second method for that in the ng-click itself ..

Comment: @Rohit, the first page keeps being in the stack, with the relative controller. Why do you want to reload it?

Comment: @AndiPavllo Because I'm modifying the service variable in second controller, and then popping back. I want the changes to be reflected back in controller 1 view.

Comment: @ManishKr.Shukla Sorry, I didn't get you?

Comment: `refresh: true` is only in master branch, not released yet. Meanwhile, one of these answers may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470198/angularjs-onsenui-reload-parent-page-on-nav-poppage-in-child-page/

Comment: @FranDios I went through that question earliers. I tried with your approach there, but there is slight glitch in navigation, when I do a `replacePage`.

Comment: If by resetting the controller, you're actually trying to reset data values in that controller, you can do so by calling another method after popage, in the ng-click attribute.

Comment: @ManishKr.Shukla Yes I can do, but the changes will not get reflected in first controller, unless we reload it.

Comment: @RohitJain I just saw your comment in the other question. As I said there, you can try with the other answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: @FranDios Ok, the other answer did work.. But it's a bit ugly. I've to explicitly pass the previous page I want to replace :(

Comment: @RohitJain I think we will add the `refresh` feature to the next release (1.3.9) since many people is asking for it :)

Comment: @FranDios :( And is the release planned anytime soon?

Comment: @RohitJain I believe within 2 weeks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `nav.resetToPage(page, options)` function, which clears the page stack and add the specified page to the new stack. The options parameter corresponds to the navigator.pushPage API.

Comment: Will `resetToPage` clear all the pages from the stack?

Comment: @RohitJain yes, it will solve your problem in case the page that you want to refresh is in the first page loaded by the navigator, otherwise is not a good solution, because it will reset also all the previous pages

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that only. It won't help in that case.

Comment: yeah sorry, I based my answer on the code you provided, not in a general situation